# Two(with subquery) or one query to select max(date) in where clause. MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I need to create a table and store there cached status of some events. So I will have to do only two operations:

1) Insert id of event, it's status, and time of when this record was stored in db;

2) Get last record with certain event id.

There are several methods to get the result (status):

Method 1:

```
SELECT status FROM status_log a
WHERE a.event_id = 1
ORDER BY a.update_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT status FROM status_log a
WHERE a.update_date = (
  SELECT max(b.update_date) FROM status_log b
  WHERE b.event_id = 1
)  AND a.event_id = 1
```

So I have two questions:

1. Which query to use
2. Which field type to set to update_date field (int or timestamp)

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: I have no table yet. So free to create any indexes. Assume to use index on update_date,event_id

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your second query does not resolve question *'find record with greatest date of update for event #1'* - because there could be many different events with same latest `update_date`. So, in terms of semantics - you should use first query. (*after your edit this is fixed*)

First query will be effective if you'll create an index by `event_id` index and this column will have good cardinality (i.e. `WHERE` clause will filter few enough rows by using that index). However, this can be improved by adding column `update_date` to index - but that makes sense only if there will be many rows with same `event_id` (many enough for MySQL to use second index part) - and again with good cardinality inside first index part.

But in practice - my advice is just a theory, you'll have to figure it out with `EXPLAIN` syntax and your own measures on real data.

As for data type - common practice is to use proper data type (i.e. datetime/timestamp for something which means time point)

Comment: Explain says that 1st query is simple with key 'event_id', key_len is 4, ref is 'const', rows = 2, and extra is 'Using where'. Second query explain says "Select tables optimized away" on subquery, primary select_type have key 'event_id', key_len 8, ref 'const,const', rows = 1, and extra is 'Using where'.

Comment: So this "Select tables optimized away" worries me very much.

Comment: "Select tables optimized away" is one of the best things you can see in your EXPLAIN. That means DBMS got desired result even _without_ reading indexes - it simply took last value (since we are talking about `MAX`)

Answer (score 1):

**Which query to use**

I believe the first one should be faster. Anyway just run an `EXPLAIN` on them and you'll find out yourself.

The index you should be using will be:

```
ALERT TABLE status_log ADD INDEX(event_id, update_date)
```

Now... did you notice that those queries are NOT equivalent? The second one will return all status from all event_id that have a maximum date.

**Which field type to set to update_date field (int or timestamp)**

If you have a field named `update_date` I just can't imagine why an `int` would serve the same purpose. Rephrasing the question to choose between `datetime` or `timestamp`, then the answer is up to the requirements. If you just want to know when a record in the DB was updated use a timestamp. If the `update_date` refers to an entity in your domain model go for a `datetime`. You will most likely need to perform calculations on the date (add time, remove time, extract a month, etc) so using a unix timestamp (which I'd say should be almost write-only) will result in extra calculation time because you'll have to convert the `timestamp` to a `datetime` and then perform the function over that result.

Comment: Sorry, mistake in 2nd query added  `AND a.event_id = 1`

Comment: So the question is if you should store a `DATETIME` or a `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: I added an explanation about it